# Is it possible for rooted phone to move internal SD to external SD?

Tags: applications, rooting, internal-storage, 5.1-lollipop

I want to make my internal space solely for app installation and then the rest of the data (e.g. big game files, etc) I want to go to my external SD instead. How do I do this with a fully rooted phone with Xposed framework and recovery and running Lollipop 5.1.1?

Comment: You could link the sdcard/Android/obb folder with sdcard2/Android/obb and just save the obb files ( big game files ) separately ! ... I think it's called symlink or something

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Start with our [app2sd tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) for the general info (especially read the "extended methods" section), and then continue to our [link2sd tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info). That should get you started :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question here now. What I ended up going with is the Xposed module called [XinternalSD](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.xinternalsd). What it does is trick the apps of your choosing to think the external SD card is the internal SD. You can choose which app to redirect so things you want to be faster (like a launcher) can be kept pointing to the internal. This module can also work on system apps so that's really nice. For example, if you set Chrome or Firefox to be redirected, when you download things, it's gonna go directly to external SD.